# How to get "this" in jQuery event binding

Tags: javascript, jquery, this, jquery-events

I have a function which is called on `keyup` or `change` but I'm struggling to get the value of `this`

**CODE**

```
var myNS = myNS || {};

myNS.validate = {
    dobChange: function(elem){
        console.log($(this).val().length); // trying to check length of "this"
    }
}

$('.dob1-day, .dob1-month, .dob1-year').on('keyup change', myNS.validate.dobChange('foo'));
```

Console error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined`

How can I get the value of `this`?

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/studiotime/w4h2ve8r/1/)

Comment: You are *calling* your function when you put `('foo')` after it. Unless the function you're calling itself returns a function, then you're doing it wrong.

Comment: [`$('.dob1-day').on('keyup change', myNS.validate.dobChange);`](https://jsfiddle.net/studiotime/w4h2ve8r/1/)

Comment: Don't want to go anonymous if can help it - what do you mean by `bind`?

Comment: Are you expecting `this` to be `myNS`?

Comment: $('.dob1-day, .dob1-month, .dob1-year').on('keyup change', function(){myNS.validate.dobChange.call(this,'foo')});

Comment: @Tushar sorry, I missed var into function - should have read `dobChange: function(elem){` hence why passing `'foo'`

Comment: Your fiddle was screaming about lowercase because you hadnt included jquery in it.

Comment: @Havihavi - yes it is

Comment: @Havihavi No jq is included. Error is because context is set on `window` which hasn't got any value property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `call()` and anonymous function to set relevant context and pass extra param:

```
$('.dob1-day').on('keyup change', function(){myNS.validate.dobChange.call(this, "foo")});
```

### -jsFiddle-

Comment: Boom!! That's a new one on me - outstanding! Many thanks

Answer (score 3):

You should extract the DOM element out of the event that is passed to the handler:

```
//getting the element
myNS.validate = {
    dobChange: function(e){
        console.log($(e.target).val().length); // trying to check length of "this"
    }
}
//calling handler
$('.dob1-day, .dob1-month, .dob1-year').on('keyup change', myNS.validate.dobChange)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.dob1-day').on('keyup change', myNS.validate.dobChange);
```

Comment: It kinda helps to have some text describing your answer, rather than a single line of code

Comment: can't do this, updated question, missed off variable into function

Answer (score 0):

```
var myNS = myNS || {};

myNS.validate = {
    dobChange: function($element){
        console.log($element.val());
  }
}

$(function () {
    $(".content").on('keyup change','.dob1-day', function(){
                        myNS.validate.dobChange($(this));
                    });
});



<div class="content">
    <input type="text" class="dob1-day">
</div>
```